# Why the performance difference between TableAdapter.Fill data sources

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, tableadapter

I have a windows form app with a `DataGridView` populated by a `TableAdapter`. I'm using the `Fill` method to update the data for the UI in a looping `Async` sub like so.

```
Private Async Sub updateUI()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    While True
        Await Task.Delay(3000)
        sw.Restart()
        'myTableAdapter.Fill(getDataWithMySQL())
        'myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)
        myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myStoredProc)
        logger.Debug(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    End While
End Sub
```

The `getDataWithMySQL` function is as follows:

```
Private Function getDataWithMySQL() As myDataSet.myDataTable
    Dim connStr As String = My.Settings.myConnectionString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ..."
    Dim dt As New myDataSet.myDataTable
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sql
                .Connection = conn
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                sqladapter.Fill(dt)

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

`myDataSet.myTable` is the same as `myDataSet.myStoredProc` except it is created by joining tables in the DataSet designer. Obviously `myDataSet.myStoredProc` is the same query in a stored procedure in the source database.

So benchmarking the `Fill` with each method using a `Stopwatch` I get the following results:

- `myDataSet.myStoredProc`
  ~750ms
- `myDataSet.myTable`
  ~550ms
- `getDataWithMySQL()`
  <10ms

So my question is, what is causing the performance difference here? I'd prefer to use `myDataSet.myTable` or `myDataSet.myStoredProc` but I don't know if it is possible to optimise them in some way so as to match the performance of `getDataWithMySQL()`.