# Tableadapter.Fill not working with manual query source

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview, tableadapter

I have a windows form app with a `DataGridView` populated by a `TableAdapter`. I'm using the `Fill` method to update the data for the UI in a looping `Async` sub like so.

```
Private Async Sub updateUI()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    While True
        Await Task.Delay(3000)
        sw.Restart()
        myTableAdapter.Fill(getDataWithMySQL())
        'myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)
        logger.Debug(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    End While
End Sub
```

The `getDataWithMySQL` function is as follows:

```
Private Function getDataWithMySQL() As myDataSet.myDataTable
    Dim connStr As String = My.Settings.myConnectionString
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ..."
    Dim dt As New myDataSet.myDataTable
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sql
                .Connection = conn
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                sqladapter.Fill(dt)

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

`myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)` works fine but performs poorly whereas `myTableAdapter.Fill(getDataWithMySQL())` performs better as reported in my as yet unanswered question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28358425/why-the-performance-difference-between-tableadapter-fill-data-sources).

For some reason, `myTableAdapter.Fill(getDataWithMySQL())` does not work any more. It doesn't throw an error and `dt` is populated with the correct data but the `DataGridView` is not updating. It has worked previously and I don't think I've changed anything that would affect this. Any ideas why the `DataGridView` is not updating?

Comment: What's the `DataGridView.DataSource` property set to? Make sure it's set to your DataTable.

Comment: @Supersnake It's set to the datatable bindingsource.

Comment: Have you set your TableAdapter's ClearBeforeFill property to true?

Comment: You can also try to call dataGridViewInstance.Refresh()...

Comment: @NeillVerreynne I tried both your suggestions but neither worked unfortunately... Why would I change `ClearBeforeFill` to `True` though?

Comment: @doovers, ClearBeforeFill was just a wild guess that it might cause a refresh. If set to true any changes made after loaded will be lost and probably not the desired result.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne Ah that's ok as I was avoiding setting it to true so as not to lose the selected cell and scrollbar positions.

Comment: It will be pretty difficult to get much help considering the complex arrangement you have going on.  Instead of returning a typed DS, why not change `getDataWithMySQL` to simply act on `MyTableAdapter`?  I'd work to simplify it all the way around.

Comment: Why is this question tagged w/ C#?

Comment: @Josh For more attention. While I'm working in VB.Net, I'd bet this case would apply equally to C# and there seems to be many more C# developers than VB.Net that might be able to weigh in with a solution.

Comment: Why do you need to fill a table that already filled?

Comment: I want to update the `DataGridView` to reflect any changes that have been made to the database table it is bound to. I also don't want to lose my position on it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem stems from the fact that you're creating a new datatable within the method call and returning that datatable. You've got a reference to the DataSet.DataTable that you want, just call Fill with that DataTable.

Your problem is that the datatable that you're filling isn't associated w/ the dataset that your grid is using.

Comment: Thanks but the problem with filling with the `DataSet.DataTable` is that the performance is so poor. It takes considerably longer to do the `Fill` that way. And while what you say about the new `DataTable` not being associated with the Grid makes sense, the `DataTable` returned by the function is of the same type, so it shouldn't make any difference. Also, as I mentioned, this was working for a while which was how I was able to benchmark the performance of each method in the other question I have linked to.

Comment: If it was working for awhile then what changed? Can you look through source control? The type has nothing to do with whether the instance is associated with the DataGrid.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what changed, I've tried everything I could think of including writing a new application with only that code to see if I could get it to work but no joy. Source control is no good either because I've been a bad boy and neglected to implement it in this project. Lesson learned though!

Comment: OK. I've got nothing else to go on then. I've tried the code using the Fill operator on a DataSet table and it works fine. The more complicated the query the slower it gets, but I haven't seen anything too bad.

Comment: One of the problems is that the query has a number of joins (5 tables) which may be slowing it down. None of the tables are very big though, the largest has 500 rows and the rest are 10-100 so it shouldn't be that bad. But >600ms vs <10ms is a massive difference when you are updating the UI every 5 seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71603/discussion-between-josh-and-doovers).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because the `.Fill` command takes a datatable in using `ByRef`. I think what's happening is you are returning a DataTable with your `getDataWithMySQL()` but then you are taking that DataTable and refilling it with the `.Fill` method of the adapter and the DataTable you were returning with the `getDataWithMySQL()` method goes into lala land to never be seen again.

Making some assumptions here, but try giving this a shot:

```vb
Private Async Sub updateUI()
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    While True
        Await Task.Delay(3000)
        sw.Restart()
        Dim dt as myDataSet.myDataTable = getDataWithMySQL("SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ...")
        UpdateDGV(dt)
        'myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)
        logger.Debug(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    End While
End Sub

' You need to change `DataGridView` here to be the actual datagridview control on the form
Private Sub UpdateDGV(newSource as myDataSet.myDataTable)
    DataGridView.SuspendLayout()
    DataGridView.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView.DataSource = newSource 
    DataDridView.ResumeLayout()
End Sub

' Make the function easier to reuse by passing in the SQL command
Private Function getDataWithMySQL(sqlCmd as string) As myDataSet.myDataTable
    Dim connStr As String = My.Settings.myConnectionString
    Dim dt As New myDataSet.myDataTable
    Using conn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
            With cmd
                .CommandText = sqlCmd
                .Connection = conn
            End With
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Dim sqladapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                sqladapter.Fill(dt)

            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While it does work, there are a few problems with this approach. Firstly, the performance is equivalent to using `myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)` and secondly the `DataGridView` loses its position which is a deal breaker. The latter can be avoided by setting `ClearBeforeFill` to `False` in the `TableAdapter` when using the `myTableAdapter.Fill(myDataSet.myTable)` method. So unfortunately, this answer defeats the purpose of doing it manually.

Comment: At least I tried... It's the thought that counts, right?

Comment: Ha ha yeah deffo!! Appreciate the help though mate!